# How to generate multiple picture boxes and control them using a timer?

Tags: vb.net

My uni asked us to make a game using VB, and I really don't know much about the language.
I'm trying to make a game where balloons go up to them top of the screen and must be popped before getting there.

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If PictureBox1.Top = 0 Then
        PictureBox1.Visible = False
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
    PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top - 1
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 1
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub


Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub

End Class
```

This is my code so far, when I click the button, the balloon starts to go up, if I click the balloon, it disappears, it also disappears if it reaches the top and the timer stops.

How can I generate more balloons and control them using that timer?

Comment: You can make a list of picturebox and create pictureboxes dynamically with an event handler (for clicking it as what you have describe).

Answer (score 0):

Now all you have let to do is add the functionality of adding more `PictureBoxes`, maybe a second timer and when you create them use an `Addhandler` statement to point them the the `pbs_Click` event that I made and add them to the `List` I made as well.

```
Public Class Form1
 Private PBs As New List(Of PictureBox)
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  For Each pb As PictureBox In PBs
    If pb.Top = 0 Then
     pb.Visible = False
     Timer1.Enabled = False
    Else
     pb.Top = pb.Top - 1
  End If
 End Sub
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Timer1.Interval = 1000'ms
  Timer1.Enabled = True
 End Sub
 Private Sub pbs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
  PBs.Remove(pb)
 End Sub
 Private Sub makeNewPB()
  Dim pb As New PictureBox
  Addhandler pb.Click, AddressOf pbs_Click
  'don't forget to make them the size you need
  PBs.Add(pb)
 End Sub
End Class
```